# Como modificar una variable global desde una funcion Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base-de-datos, scroll

Amigos, quisiera que me ayuden guiandome, necesito modificar una variable global al momento de hacer scroll, para cargar datos mediante Ajax.

El codigo que escribi, funciona la primera vez cuando el scroll llega al final de la pagina, pero luego cuando hago scroll nuevamente, llega al final y se cargan los mismos datos infinitamente. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
var flag_scroll;

            $(window).scroll(function(){    
                    if($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                            $('#ForLoadMore1').html("<div id='loadingDraw' style='width100%; height35px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;'><img src='imagenes/loading.gif' style='width:135px; height:100px;'></div>");
                            setTimeout(function(){$('#loadingDraw').hide()}, 2000);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:'loadMore.php',
                                    type:'GET',
                                    data:{
                                        'offset':flag_scroll,
                                        'limit':10
                                    },
                                    success:function(data){
                                        if(data != ""){
                                            $('#ForLoadMore1').append(data);
                                            flag_scroll =+ 10;
                                        } else {
                                            $('#ForLoadMore1').append("<p>No hay más noticias para mostrar!</p>");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }, 2000); 
                    }
            });
```

Este es el codigo PHP:

```
<?php
//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "********";
$pw = "******";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

if(isset($_GET['limit']) && isset($_GET['offset'])){
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $dataBase1) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");

            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion)); 

            while($final = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

                echo "<div class=\"not7\"><div class=\"fotosMain3\" id=\"foto18\"><img src='".$final['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'></div><div class=\"TextoDerecha\"><h3 id=\"Etiqueta16\" style=\"color: #10A2E5; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;\">".$final['Etiqueta']."</h3><hr class=\"barrasNuevas\" size=\"1px\" width=\"100%\" noshade=\"noshade\" style=\"margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3;\"><h1 class=\"titulosMain3\" id=\"Titulo19\">".$final['Titulo']."</h1><h1 class=\"Subtitulos\" id=\"Subtitulo15\">".$final['Subtitulo']."</h1><p style=\"color: #2E2E2E; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;\">Por: <span style=\"color: #1279a8;\">".$final['Autor']."<span style=\"color: #2E2E2E;\">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span>".$final['Fecha']."</span></p><p class=\"main3Textos\" id=\"main3Textos-12\">".substr($final['Texto'], 0, 300)."...</p></div></div>";

            }
        //}
}

?>
```

He hecho las siguientes modificaciones, recomendadas por colegas que han respondido mi pregunta, son las siguientes:

1) Agregue la opcion 
    async:false,
al la funcion $.ajax.

2) Inicialicé la variable global flag_scroll:
    var flag_scroll = 21;
Porque necesito que los datos carguen a partir de la fila 21 de la tabla de la base de datos, ya que las filas 1 - 20 cargan cuando la pagina inicia.

3) Agregue un alert en el success para monitorear el incremento de la variable flag_scroll
    alert(flag_scroll);

Pero aun no consigo lo que necesito, el codigo actualizado seria:
    var flag_scroll = 21;

```
            $(window).scroll(function(){    
                    if($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                            $('#ForLoadMore1').html("<div id='loadingDraw' style='width100%; height35px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;'><img src='imagenes/loading.gif' style='width:135px; height:100px;'></div>");
                            setTimeout(function(){$('#loadingDraw').hide()}, 2000);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    async:false,
                                    url:'loadMore.php',
                                    type:'GET',
                                    data:{
                                        'offset':flag_scroll,
                                        'limit':10
                                    },
                                    success:function(data){
                                        if(data != ""){
                                            $('#ForLoadMore1').append(data);
                                            alert(flag_scroll);
                                            flag_scroll += 10;
                                        } else {
                                            $('#ForLoadMore1').append("<p>No hay más noticias para mostrar!</p>");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }, 2000); 
                    }
            });
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:
Al hacer scroll hasta el final de la pagina, aparece el primer alert con mensaje "21", doy click en aceptar, se cargan 10 datos como se espera. Al hacer scroll nuevamente, aparece el segundo alert con mensaje "31" pero al dar click en Aceptar, aparece el tercer alert SIN HABER HECHO scroll y me muestra "41"

Podrian ayudarme a encontrar el error por favor?

Comment: el problema es que la llamada de AJAX es asincrona, por lo tanto siempre termina despues de la asignacion de la variable, la solucion corta es poner el parametro **async: false** a la funcion de AJAX. El problema viene cuando la llamada tarda, entonces la pagina se bloquea

Comment: Rene Limon, que deberia hacer si es que quiero iniciar la variable flag_scroll desde 21.??

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en una sola línea de código:

Debes cambiar esto:

```
flag_scroll =+ 10;
```

Por esto:

```
flag_scroll += 10;
```

El resto del código lo veo bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, que deberia hacer si quiero iniciar la variable flag_scroll desde 21... Ya que requiero que al finalizar el scroll, traiga datos desde la fila 21, ya que las filas 1 - 20, ya se cargan cuando la pagina se abre.

Comment: Pues en el success haces flag_scroll = 21; no? y ya cuando vuelva a entrar al ajax llevará ese valor.

Comment: Puedo inicializar la variable global flag_scroll = 21;

Comment: Si claro la puedes iniciar en el valor que desees, lo importante es que para sumar y asignar se usa += y no =+

Comment: Me esta funcionando lo que me has ayudado, pero aun tengo un pequeno error... lo que pasa es que puse un alert justo despues del success para comprobar el incremento de flag_scroll:

success:function(data){
              if(data != ""){
                  $('#ForLoadMore1').append(data);
                  alert(flag_scroll);
                  flag_scroll += 10;

efectivamente se muestra el incremento, pero no se por que despues del 2do scroll pasa esto:

1er scroll -> "21"
2do scroll -> "31" doy click en OK y aparece un nuevo alert mostrando "41" sin haber hecho scroll

Comment: Cuéntame el error !

Comment: lo que pasa es que puse un alert justo despues del success para comprobar el incremento de flag_scroll:

success:function(data){
              if(data != ""){
                  $('#ForLoadMore1').append(data);
                  alert(flag_scroll);
                  flag_scroll += 10;

efectivamente se muestra el incremento, pero no se por que despues del 2do scroll pasa esto:

1er scroll -> "21"......      
           2do scroll -> "31"...... doy click en OK y aparece un nuevo alert mostrando "41" sin haber hecho scroll

Comment: Por que el scroll se ejecuta varias veces en el código, si tu después de esta línea $(window).scroll(function(){   colocas un alert o un console.log('hola mundo') vas a ver que se repite varias veces, puedes intentar colocando return false; después de flag_scroll += 10;  pero no se a ciencia cierta si te funcionaría